# Asp.net Core with Identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have 2 website that are using identity server Authentication (which is a third website)

if i log out from the identity server website (i am using quick start) how can i force the 2 other website to validate if the user is still log in, and this on every round trip to the server (post back).

Comment: Your access token is authenticated on every request you shouldn't have to do anything

Comment: May be wrong, but I think if the access token is self-contained (i.e. JWT) it will not be re-validated on every request as it is a protected structure signed by the issuer and will remain valid until it expires. I think OP probably needs to switch to using reference tokens: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For browser based apps you can call the [session endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html):

> All applications that the user has logged into via the browser during
>   the user’s session can participate in the sign-out.

This will however not invalidate JWT tokens as these are self-contained and remain valid until expiration.

The only way to logout a JWT 'almost realtime', is to set the expiration to a minimum and use refresh tokens to renew the access token.

These refresh tokens can be revoked using the [revocation endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/revocation.html):

> This endpoint allows revoking access tokens (reference tokens only)
>   and refresh token.

This way you don't need a roundtrip on each call. An alternative that does is to use [reference tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html):

> When using reference tokens - IdentityServer will store the contents
>   of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier
>   for this token back to the client. The API receiving this reference
>   must then open a back-channel communication to IdentityServer to
>   validate the token.

Using the revocation endpoint you can revoke the reference tokens at any time you like.